# How do I know what are the complete custom options for Android's actionbar styling?

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

In my styles.xml, I would like to know the complete styling options for the action bar.

The problem is that Eclipse doesn't auto-complete them to me.

I found some bits and pieces in different places, but I would like the complete options/attributes list.

Example - Even the attribute `android:actionBarStyle` was not offered in the auto-complete and I found it in the documentation:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

There are a lot more that I found that are not documented, like `android:actionOverflowButtonStyle`, which is related to the actionbar but not found in the actionbar's style.

**What is the complete list of attributes that can custom the action bar style?** From background to split to actionmode to actions to overflow to tabs to home, etc...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all of the attributes in the [`R.attr` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html) (hint: they all start with `action`). Some of these may be unrelated (like `actionViewClass`), but the ones you can use should all be contained here.

```
actionBarDivider
actionBarItemBackground
actionBarSize
actionBarSplitStyle
actionBarStyle
actionBarTabBarStyle
actionBarTabStyle
actionBarTabTextStyle
actionBarWidgetTheme
actionButtonStyle
actionDropDownStyle
actionLayout
actionMenuTextAppearance
actionMenuTextColor
actionModeBackground
actionModeCloseButtonStyle
actionModeCloseDrawable
actionModeCopyDrawable
actionModeCutDrawable
actionModePasteDrawable
actionModeSelectAllDrawable
actionModeSplitBackground
actionModeStyle
actionOverflowButtonStyle
actionProviderClass
actionViewClass
```

There are also [themes, from `R.style`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html) (use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find "ActionBar"), or [styleable attributes for the Action Bar from `R.styleable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html).

Comment: By convention? Sigh... Thanks. Anyways, how do I know the possible options within each and every style. For example backgroundSplit can be put in  actionBarStyle, but I don't know how I found that out and if I can use it in other styles.

Comment: @kilaka Honestly, I'm not sure that's documented. The Action Bar stuff is very poorly documented (as you've discovered); most of them I believe are expected to take style parameters using resources from `@android` or `?android`. You may have to learn these on a case-by-case basis... If you ever decide to make your own documentation on it, you could always link back to it here!

Comment: Eric, sorry for not giving your answer the V. It's not complete enough. The point is that probably no one could have given a complete answer - the AB in Android is a mystery :(

Comment: @kilaka Oh, well, it is what it is I suppose. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice place to start with: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/screen_action_bar.xml

It's the overall screen content, separated into actionbar/actionmode, content and splitactionbar.

It defines 3 styles: `?android:attr/actionBarStyle`, `?android:attr/actionModeStyle` and `?android:attr/actionBarSplitStyle`

How do go from there, like knowing that actionBarStyle can hold indeterminateProgressStyle, or how to style the tabs, I really don't know :(